# How can I prevent photoswipe to unbind my scroll event?

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

[**situation**]
I have problems about photoswipe close. I have a html page A using Photoswipe for a photo view. I have defined a scroll event in page A. When I open and then close photoswipe and go back to my page A, the scroll event is not working any more.

My scroll event:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ((getDocumentHeight() - getWindowHeight() - getSrollHeight()) == 0) {
    alert("buttom");
  };
});
```

I noticed photoswipe's close and destory method call `_unbindEvents`  methods, which executes the unbind function.

```
// Closes the gallery, then destroy it
close: function() {
    if(!_isOpen) {
        return;
    }

    _isOpen = false;
    _isDestroying = true;
    _shout('close');
    _unbindEvents();

    _showOrHide( self.currItem, null, true, self.destroy);
},
// destroys gallery (unbinds events, cleans up intervals and timeouts to avoid memory leaks)
destroy: function() {
    _shout('destroy');

    if(_showOrHideTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(_showOrHideTimeout);
    }

    template.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
    template.className = _initalClassName;

    if(_updateSizeInterval) {
        clearInterval(_updateSizeInterval);
    }

    framework.unbind(self.scrollWrap, _downEvents, self);

    // we unbind lost event at the end, as closing animation may depend on it
    framework.unbind(window, 'scroll', self);

    _stopDragUpdateLoop();

    _stopAllAnimations();

    _listeners = null;
},
_unbindEvents = function() {
    framework.unbind(window, 'resize', self);
    framework.unbind(window, 'scroll', _globalEventHandlers.scroll);
    framework.unbind(document, 'keydown', self);
    framework.unbind(document, 'mousemove', _onFirstMouseMove);

    if(_features.transform) {
        framework.unbind(self.scrollWrap, 'click', self);
    }

    if(_isDragging) {
        framework.unbind(window, _upMoveEvents, self);
    }

    _shout('unbindEvents');
},
```

[**question**]
How can I prevent photoswipe to unbind my scroll event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem.

```
$(document).scroll()
```

instead of

```
$(window).scroll()
```

It's working.

Answer (score 0):

Never used photoswipe, but according to the comment

```
// we unbind lost event at the end, as closing animation 'may' depend on it
```

what happens if you remove the line?

```
framework.unbind(window, 'scroll', self);
```

Comment: I have tried this, but my scroll event is still not working. And there is an error occured. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateScrollOffset' of null